# correct strategy for MacBook Pro M1 32GB 2T repeated kernel panics

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

Some background: I bought the computer on May 2023, and ever since I keep getting kernel panic approximately every 3 weeks. I want to have the computer replaced but I need it for work and can't allow myself just giving it to the lab, which I don't believe do anything useful except formatting the disk and give it back to me after a week only to discover it is still crashing. Therefore I have to be smart and have the computer replaced without in-between time wasting. I have invested a lot in analyzing panic logs (was useless), system logs, I even wrote a service which monitors processes and system errors every 20 minutes. However, nothing in the logs can explain the panics. I believe panic is happening too fast to have any log indication.
my questions are:

1. What is best strategy to have the computer replaced, while minimizing "no computer" time, minimizing OS installations, minimizing file-copying?
2. what is the probability that this is related with external hdmi monitor (I think low, because why would it take 3 weeks to tigger panic?!)
3. what is the probability that clean MacOS install (I used migration assistant when I got the M1) will fix the issue?

Comment: Every 3 weeks is quite specific: is there any activity that might be synchronous with the panics?

Comment: @benwiggy this is just an average. real dates are:

* 30-Sep-23   10:49
* 4-Sep-23   18:35
* 19-Aug-23   21:40 
* 2-Aug-23 
July - forgot to document 
* 13-Jun-23   10:55
* 7-Jun-23   23:25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after installing MacOS Sonoma more than a month ago, the crashes seem to have gone. it's a shame, because: such a severe issue should be addressed on all supported MacOS's, I never imagined that the issue would left untouched in MacOS Monterey but fixed in Sonoma, and even if I had installed Sonoma when it was out, I would still have had those crashes for 5 months, from May 23 (MacBook Pro purchase) to Sep 26 (Sonoma released) but better late than never

Comment: So glad you got it sorted. Some things that I either missed or you didn't state: 1) Are you opting in to submitting all crash reports to Apple and third party developers? 2) Were you ever able to cause a panic or predict one specifically to a few minutes in time?

Comment: 1-yes  2-no  [filler-text]

Comment: Good. The former helps them over time fix things slowly. The latter helps you fix it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The first option: I would take it to an Apple Store, and have them diagnose whether there is a hardware problem, which they should be able to do at an in-person appointment, while you wait. If that's the case, then they are also the people you talk to about getting a free replacement. (Or the shop where you bought it, if different.)

Alternatively:

***What is the probability that a clean MacOS install (I used migration assistant when I got the M1) will fix the issue?***

You don't need to reinstall the OS: you just  **Erase All Content and Settings**, in **System Settings > General**.  Then, see if the machine works without panics. Then migrate your files, and SELECTIVELY re-install your apps.

Duff Macs straight from the factory do happen, but the odds are very low; and the odds of you migrating something from your old Mac that doesn't play nicely are much higher.

Another thing you could do is download [EtreCheck](https://etrecheck.com/en/index.html), which is an app that produces a useful report of the 'state' of your Mac, which is useful in trouble-shooting problems (particularly remotely).

Paste the report in your question, and someone here may be able to notice something that might ring alarm bells. *(The report is entirely anonymous data, and it's a well-known and respected app.)*

Comment: i have etreCheck since June or July, I followed every recommendation it gave (such as removing old Intel services, unsigned services etc.) it didn't help.  In the Apple store they surely wouldn't be able to diagnose the panics, otherwise they would have done this in the factory already before shipping to me. remember, it takes 3 weeks from boot until a panic is happening. Apple service already told me that they will take the computer to their lab (leaving me with nothing), this is the reason to that post.

Comment: @NirO. The EtreCheck report will also include a list of software, like Launch Agents, that might be causing the problem. Your certainty that they "surely can't diagnose hardware problems" is misplaced. You have nothing to lose by trying.

Comment: of course I have something to lose here. that's what the post is about. first, I will have to spend a few days in obtaining a replacement computer and install my dozens of work software and enable the license setup certificates etc. then, copy all the files to the backup media, then go to Apple and be left without the new MacBook for 3 weeks, after which they will solemnly declared "fixed!" after a format and installing MacOS anew, and me returning back to square one with eventually a defected computer. that's pretty much time and energy for nothing

Comment: @NirO. You seem to have already made up your mind about what you think will happen. Perhaps it's worth checking if your assumptions are true first? As I said: you should be able to get a while-you-wait diagnosis in an Apple Store appointment. If there is a hardware fault, then they will replace the logic board. I've had that in less than a week.

Comment: the hardware fault which you had, how easy was it to reproduce the problem? (possible answers might be - A)a  consistent problem   B) happening only after a few minutes  C) happening after a few weeks and may require someone actively working on the computer to reproduce...)

Comment: @NirO. Why not see what actually happens with your Mac, rather than second guessing what might happen. Alternatively, you can try erasing all content, and being selective about what you reinstall; or booting from an external. Both of those would rule out a hardware problem, if all works. Another option is listing the Etrecheck report, so that we can see if there's anything that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I'm with Ben - proceed immediately to an erase and test period for however long you can stand to make before bringing apps back. With once every three months, it's very unlikely it's a hardware fault and very likely it's software - following Apple's guidance will also minimize your time to isolate and resolve this: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-your-mac-restarts-and-a-message-appears-mchlp2890/mac